# Team alert for build completion not firing

Tags: email, tfsbuild

In TFS 2012, I've created a new Team, and then a new group that includes just me, and finally a new Team Alert that fires on build completion. I manually kick off a build and do not get any emails. Still trying to figure out if I can get alerts if I setup my own individual alerts. I know others are getting emails for code reviews so I suspect email settings are correct. Any tips appreciated.

Comment: where are you created the alert?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Problem sorted. I had the wrong email address in my TFS Profile.